# Memcached not working with PHP5.6 from Webtatic

Tags: linux, memcached, php-5.6

Need your help with memcached with PHP 5.6.
Environment: CentOS7.1, configuration built with yum through WEBTATIC repo.
Memcached service running (telnet working), but the PHP code fails to store and get variables in/from Memcache / Memcached.
Code:

```html
$meminstance = new Memcache();
$meminstance->pconnect('localhost', 11211);
$meminstance->set('testa', 'A OK', 0, 600);
echo ' Testing Memcache... ';
echo $meminstance->get('testa').' --- end<br>';

$cache = new Memcached();
$cache->addServer('localhost', 11211);
$cache->set('testc','C OK', 0, 600);
$cache->set('testd','D OK', 600);
echo ' Testing Memcached... ';
echo $cache->get('testc').' '.$cache->get('testd').' --- end';
```

phpinfo on the development server:
http://b.luckstock.com/testp.php?phpinfo

No errors seen in logs. Removed and re-installed memcache/memcached and php-modules several times, nothing helps. Out of ideas. Any help?

Comment: I've just found out that running "php testp.php" from command line on the server works perfectly, though it doesn't work from browser.
Thinking it could be php-fpm related issue then.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was SELinux preventing access to Memcached via browser.
To fix it, run the command on the server once:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_memcache 1
```